# Is there a way to limit Material UI TextFields of input type = file to accept only pdf?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, input-type-file

I am trying to make my input type=file to limit the user to only upload pdf.

I looked it up and saw that using accept attribute can help. But it is not working using material UI text fields.

Any solution I can try?

Comment: you can use the accept attribute `<input type="file" accept=".pdf">`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```js
<TextField type={"file"} inputProps={{accept:"application/pdf"}}/>
```

Comment: Great, just add `type="file"`

Comment: In `inputProps` it works too, but `TextField` itself accepts `type` prop :)

Comment: I wasn't sure if it accepted all the input types

Comment: Yeah, actually it accepts any valid HTML5 input type.

Answer (score 0):

<TextField type={"file"} inputProps={{accept:"application/pdf"}}/>

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.